# TensorFlow - restore if present

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to restore a variable, only if present? What is the most idiomatic way of doing so?

For instance, consider the following minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import glob
import sys
import os

with tf.variable_scope('volatile'):
    x = tf.get_variable('x', initializer=0)

with tf.variable_scope('persistent'):
    y = tf.get_variable('y', initializer=0)
    add1 = tf.assign_add(y, 1)

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, 'persistent'))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
tf.get_default_graph().finalize()

print('save file', sys.argv[1])
if glob.glob(sys.argv[1] + '*'):    
    saver.restore(sess, sys.argv[1])

print(sess.run(y))
sess.run(add1)
print(sess.run(y))
saver.save(sess, sys.argv[1])
```

When run twice with the same argument, the program first prints `0\n1` and then `1\n2` as expected. Now suppose you update your code to have new functionality, by adding a `z = tf.get_variable('z', initializer=0)` after `add1` within the `persistent` scope. Running this again when the old save file is present will break with the following:

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key persistent/z not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_1 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_INT32],
         _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0,
                                                                 save/RestoreV2_1/tensor_names,
                                                                 save/RestoreV2_1/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save/Assign_1/_18 = _Recv[client_terminated=false,
         recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
         send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
         send_device_incarnation=1,
         tensor_name="edge_12_save/Assign_1",
         tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
         _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function for restoring (taken from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1823)):

```py
def optimistic_restore(session, save_file, graph=tf.get_default_graph()):
    reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(save_file)
    saved_shapes = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
    var_names = sorted([(var.name, var.name.split(':')[0]) for var in tf.global_variables()
            if var.name.split(':')[0] in saved_shapes])    
    restore_vars = []    
    for var_name, saved_var_name in var_names:            
        curr_var = graph.get_tensor_by_name(var_name)
        var_shape = curr_var.get_shape().as_list()
        if var_shape == saved_shapes[saved_var_name]:
            restore_vars.append(curr_var)
    opt_saver = tf.train.Saver(restore_vars)
    opt_saver.restore(session, save_file)
```

I usually run a `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` to make sure all variables are initialized, and then I run `optimistic_restore(sess,...)` to restore the variables which can be restored.

Answer (score 0):

You can make two savers, one for restoring the variables in the checkpoint and one for saving those variables from the checkpoint and the newly added variables. To restore variables in the checkpoint, **all variables bounded to the saver should be in the checkpoint**(that's the reason the error occurs), and if you do this way, you should first initialize all variables before restoring part of the defined variables which exist in the checkpoint.